# Django couldn't find my module if it is imported from a templetetag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm upgrading an existing Django project to v1.7 and creating some templatetags to simplify working with templates. I've created some before, but one of them is giving the following error:

`ImportError raised loading recaptcha.templatetags.recaptcha: No module named utils`.

This module looks like this:

```
- recaptcha
     |- templatetags
     |         |- __init__.py
     |         |- recaptcha.py
     |
     |- __init__.py
     |- utils.py
```

The problematic import is in **recaptcha.py** and I tried `from recaptcha import utils`, `from recaptcha.utils import myfunction` and `import recaptcha` but none of them works. If I only import recaptcha and I try to execute `dir` on it, it shows nothing.

The weird thing is that if I import the **utils** module inside another django app in a view.py or a model.py file it works perfectly. Also I tried using `manage.py shell` and it works too.

As a clarification, this project does **not** use virtualenv right now.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried with a relative import  i.e. `from .. import utils`?

Comment: @dhke you are right too, sorry, I didn't see it before. Is it because of the way I created this django app?

Comment: @neoKore I have no idea. Django sets up `sys.path` to point to the project root. This is also true when importing templatetags, so I have no idea where the problem really stems from.

Comment: @dhke I found why it failed and posted on the answer: using the same name. As long as the project was working before with an old version of django I didn't realize that this could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that @catavaran answered before works: **using a relative import** like `from ..utils import myfunction`

The problem was that the templatetag module `recaptcha.py` and the django app `recaptcha` **had both the same name**, so when I type `from recaptcha import utils` **it tries to find it from itself instead of from the `recaptcha` module**. I renamed the django app to `catpcha` and it imports the module without problem.

@catavaran I don't really know why your answer is deleted, but if you post it again I'll mark it as the right one, you deserve the kudos!